# view page does not bring me back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code like below. I expect when I click the "Save" button the view page can bring me back to controller [HttpPost] "ProductEdit", but it does not. Anybody can help me out will be great appreciate. Please check the view and control coding below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using MvcApplication1.Models;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ProductEdit(Int32 ProductId)
        {
            var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

            var q = from p in northwind.Products
                    where p.ProductID == ProductId
                    select new ProductEditViewModel
                    {
                        ProductID = p.ProductID,
                        ProductName = p.ProductName,
                        UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,

                        SupplierItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers
                                        select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = sup.CompanyName,
                                                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sup.SupplierID),
                                                Selected = sup.SupplierID == p.SupplierID
                                            },

                        CategorySelectedId = p.CategoryID,
                        CategorieItems = from cat in northwind.Categories select cat,

                        Discontinued = p.Discontinued
                    };

            return View(q.SingleOrDefault());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProductEdit()
        {
            var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

            var vm = new ProductEditViewModel();

            UpdateModel<ProductEditViewModel>(vm);

            return View();
        }
    }
}


@model MvcApplication1.Models.ProductEditViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ProductEdit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Product</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the model type of the view? You know you are not getting any model data in your post action? What does your button do instead?

Comment: `public ActionResult ProductEdit()` => `public ActionResult ProductEdit(ProductEditViewModel model)`?

Comment: What actually happens when you click Save?

Comment: Have you tried putting ProductEditViewModel as a parameter in your HttpPost ProductEdit action?

Comment: When Click Save button nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (Not Post Back from View to [HttpPost] Controller) is cause by the follow code line

```
Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sup.SupplierID),
```

So the correction code is :

---

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(Int32 ProductId)
{
    var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

    var q = from p in northwind.Products.AsEnumerable()  //to enumerate all records in memory and then use ToString
            where p.ProductID == ProductId
            select new ProductEditViewModel
            {
                Product = p,

                SupplierItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers.AsEnumerable()  //to enumerate all records in memory and then use ToString
                                select new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = sup.CompanyName,
                                        Value = sup.SupplierID.ToString(),  //to enumerate all records in memory and then use ToString
                                        Selected = sup.SupplierID == p.SupplierID
                                    },

                CategorySelectedId = p.CategoryID,
                CategorieItems = from cat in northwind.Categories.AsEnumerable() select cat,  //to enumerate all records in memory and then use ToString
            };

    return View(q.SingleOrDefault());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(ProductEditViewModel vm)
{
    return View();
}
```

---

```
public class ProductEditViewModel
{
    public Product Product;

    // For DropDownListFor need IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }

    // For RadioButtonFor need below
    public Int32? CategorySelectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> CategorieItems { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.SupplierID, "SupplierID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*DropDownList is for deiplay purpose*@
        @*@Html.DropDownList("SupplierID", Model.SupplierItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@

        @*DropDownListFor is for Edit purpose*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product.SupplierID, Model.SupplierItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.CategoryID, "CategoryID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*RadioButton is for Display purpose*@
        @*@foreach (var Categorie in Model.CategorieItems)
            {
                @Html.RadioButton("CategoryID", Categorie.CategoryID, Model.CategorySelectedId == Categorie.CategoryID) @Categorie.CategoryName; @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            }*@

        @*RadioButtonFor is for Edit purpose*@
        @foreach (var Categorie in Model.CategorieItems)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CategorySelectedId, Categorie.CategoryID) @Categorie.CategoryName; @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Probably using the Html.BeginForm correctly could help:

Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", Method)

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductEdit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: That's exactly the default behavior http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244%28v=vs.118%29.aspx so it isn't the issue here.